# How to generate token using passport.js while signing in locally and not with any other social media channel?

Tags: node.js, authentication, token, passport.js

I am trying to generate token while logging in locally. Let's say I am normal user and want to sign in. Will token get generated while signing in? and how? Need guidance. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I am using mongodb I require my users schema model in my routes code.Here is my routes code `user.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('../models/schema');
var Verify    = require('./verify');

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    User.register(new User({ username : req.body.username,email: req.body.email, phone:req.body.phone }),req.body.password,
      function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({err: err});
        }
        passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
            return res.status(200).json({status: 'Registration Successful!'});
        });
    });
});

router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
          return res.status(401).json({
        err: info
      });
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
          err: 'Could not log in user'
        });
      }

      var token = Verify.getToken(user);
              res.status(200).json({
        status: 'Login successful!',
        success: true,
        token: token
      });
    });
  })(req,res,next);
});

router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'Bye!'
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

When you look at the code you will notice a verify variable.It is nothing but verification that is user is registered or not.If user registered then user will allow for login.After login user will get a successfull response along with token.So here is my veirfy code `verify.js`

```
var User=require('../models/schema');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
var config = require('../config.js');

exports.getToken = function (user) {
    return jwt.sign(user, config.secretKey, {
        expiresIn: 3600
    });
};

exports.verifyOrdinaryUser = function (req, res, next) {
    // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
    var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

    // decode token
    if (token) {
        // verifies secret and checks exp
        jwt.verify(token, config.secretKey, function (err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                var err = new Error('You are not authenticated!');
                err.status = 401;
                return next(err);
            } else {
                // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
                req.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        // if there is no token
        // return an error
        var err = new Error('No token provided!');
        err.status = 403;
        return next(err);
    }
};
```

If you observe the code there is a variable like config this is nothing but connection to my mongodb.Here is the code  `config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    'secretKey': '12345-67890-09876-54321',
    'mongoUrl' : 'mongodb://localhost:27017/conFusion'
}
```

And the user schema is here `schema.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
var User= new Schema({

username:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true
    },
email:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true
    },
phone:{
        type:Number,
        required:true,
        unique:true 
    },
password:{
        type:String
        }

});

User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',User);
```

And finally server code `app.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var config = require('./config');

mongoose.connect(config.mongoUrl);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");
});
var users = require('./routes/users');
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
var User = require('./models/schema');
app.use(passport.initialize());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
app.use('/users', users);
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
app.listen(3000,function(){
console.log("Server Listening on 3000");
});
module.exports = app;
```

`project structure` must be as per my code

```
+app.js
+config.js
+routes(directory)
 ++user.js
 ++verify.js
+models(directory)
 ++schema.js
```

run the code `node app.js`

When you want to register use `http://localhost:3000/users/register`
and for login use `http://localhost:3000/users/login`

Comment: It look's like I need to use jwt module, which is responsible to generate token, right?

Comment: yes.I require it in verify code.When you see the users route code there I am calling a Verify.getToken() function during login.When a user is registered then token is generated.

Comment: Yes. I am using mysql, so I need to convert that into mysql. Will let you know when I'll get stuck anywhere. Thanks for your kind help :)

Comment: You have posted two files of user.js. Can you please provide me this project using github? As I am unable to understand the project folder's schema. It will be easy for me to install modules as well.

Comment: Ayesha, I have now created the project structure as you guided me in the last phase.

Comment: Is it okk ???and you can see the files in my github repositories https://github.com/Syedayesha/passport.git

Comment: Yes, now it's ok. Thank you for your time out. Working on it right now