# Passport-jwt Unauthorized

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js

I'm New to node js. I'm using passport jwt for authentication. When i tried to authenticate, its always showing "unauthorized".

my *passport.js* file

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const User = require('../models/user');
const config = require('../config/database');

module.exports = function(passport){
  let opts = {};
  opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
  opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
  passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {

    User.getUserById(jwt_payload._doc._id, (err, user) => {
      if(err){
        return done(err, false);
      }

      if(user){
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        return done(null, false);
      }
    });
  }));
}
```

user model user.js

```
module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
  User.findById(id, callback);
}
```

routes

```
router.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}), (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({user: req.user});
});
```

When I google it many suggested to change this line in passport.js

```
User.getUserById(jwt_payload._doc._id, (err, user) => {
```

I tried with

```
User.getUserById(jwt_payload._id, (err, user) => {
User.findById(jwt_payload._id, (err, user) => {
```

still now i'm getting this same error.

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/45750615/7635845.This is my answer.Hope this helps.If it helps do upvote.Otherwise let me know if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out the issue,
In new passport-jwt updates, we have to use

```
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt');
```

Comment: I am doing the same thing and made the change suggested, but still getting unauthorized.here is the link to my code [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46219984/authorization-issue-using-passport-jwt)

Comment: @cacev000, check your jwt_payload  `console.log('test',jwt_payload);
    User.getUserById(jwt_payload.data._id, (err, user) => {`., sometimes your _id is under `jwt_payload.doc._id`

Answer (score 6):

if you are using `opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();` as your `jwtFromRequest` then your *Authorization* header is like

> bearer xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz

you can check the **BEARER_AUTH_SCHEME** specified in the `extract_jwt.js` located in the `passport-jwt/lib` folder

---

if you are using `opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt')` as your `jwtFromRequest` then your *Authorization* header is like

> JWT xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz

you can check the **LEGACY_AUTH_SCHEME** specified in the `extract_jwt.js` located in the `passport-jwt/lib` folder